# C++ Weird string/char* exception behaviour

Tags: c++, arrays, string, exception, stdstring

Well here is my exception code :

```
class OptionNotFoundError: public std::exception {
public:
    OptionNotFoundError(std::string option, int position) throw()
        : option(option), position(position) {}
    OptionNotFoundError(char option_, int position) throw()
        : position(position) { option.push_back(option_); }

    virtual ~OptionNotFoundError() throw() {}

    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        std::string what_str = "Option '" + option + "' not found in position " + std::to_string(position);
        std::cout << what_str.c_str() << std::endl;
        return what_str.c_str();;
    }

    std::string option;
    int position;
};
```

When the exception is thrown, here is what I get in the terminal :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Args::OptionNotFoundError'
Option 'c' not found in position 1
  what():
```

So the `cout` works fine, but… not the return. If I use `return "smth"` it works fine.

Weirder : if I replace what_str definition with

```
std::string what_str = "test";
```

I get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Args::OptionNotFoundError'
test
  what():  x�zL�
```

Again, the `cout<<` works fine. But the return… Not so much. Is this some encoding error ?

Comment: There's tonns of duplicates for this UB...

Comment: Consider making `std::string what_str;` a member variable of the `OptionNotFoundError` class instead of a local variable inside of the `what()` function.  Then `what_str` would still be alive and kicking instead of being destroyed on return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 1st case, note that `what_str` is a local variable inside `what()`, it'll be destroyed when get out of the function scope, then the pointer returned by it becomes dangled, dereference on it leads to UB.

For the 2nd case, returning `"smth"` works fine, because `"smth"` is a `const char[5]`, which is a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal),

> String literals have static storage duration, and thus exist in memory for the life of the program.

For the 3rd case,

> if i replace `what_str` definition with
>
> ```
> std::string what_str = "test";
> ```

It doesn't work, because `what_str` is still a local `std::string`, the problem is same with the 1st case.

Comment: …That's right. At first I wrote the whole code inline (without "temp" string variables) (and it didn't work better) so I didnt thought of the lifetime of what char* pointed…

Comment: I moved what_str outside what() as a member of the class, that works fine ^^

Comment: @Salamandar Yes it's a valid solution. Note that any change on the member will invalidate the returned pointer, be careful.

Answer (score 4):

```
    return what_str.c_str();;
```

`c_str()` returns a pointer to the internal contents of the `std::string`.

This pointer remains valid only until either

1. The `std::string` object gets destroyed.
2. The `std::string` object gets modified.

The `std::string` object from which this `c_str()` pointer is obtained gets destroyed when your function returns.

This results in undefined behavior.

The `const char *` that your function returns is not valid. It's pointing to the internal contents of a destroyed object.